# How to use viewmodel in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I need a view model which should contain In_time,date,Out_time,asset

Model

```
 public class Book_Model
 {
            [Key]
            public int id { get; set; }
            public string name { get; set; }
            public string phone { get; set; }
            public string department { get; set; }
            public string asset { get; set; }
            public string date { get; set; }

            public TimeSpan In_time{ get; set;}

            public TimeSpan Out_time{ get; set;}
 }
```

My view model

```
public class Book_View
{    
       public string date { get; set; }    
       public TimeSpan In_time{ get; set; }    
       public TimeSpan Out_time{ get; set; }    
       public List<Book_Model> book { get; set; }
}
```

Controller

```
           BookIn_View bv = new BookIn_View 
            {
                book = db.bookm.Where(x => x.date == date && x.In_time >= 
                In_time&& x.out_time <= Out_time).ToList()



            };
            return View(bv);
```

View

```
                @foreach (var item in Model.book)
                {
                    @item.asset


                }
```

but return Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
Help

Comment: well, this statement doesn't make sense to me `BookIn_View bv = new BookinView`

Comment: created dynamically typed added      @model Asset_Automation.ViewModel.BookIn_View

Comment: Can anyone correct me where i am wrong

Comment: make sure `book = db.bookm.Where(x => x.date == date && x.In_time >= 
In_time && x.out_time <= Out_time).ToList()` returns data and not `null`

Comment: you should `var booksList = dbContext.dbTable.Where().Where().Where().ToList();` and in your BookIn_View instantiation `var bv = new BookIn_View { book = booksList }` this will allow you to place a breakpoint just before instantiating the new bookin_view and make sure your booksList has the expected value

Comment: @Stavm when cshtml run it throws exception. This section is in post.What i can do?

Answer (score 0):

At the top of the page, have you written
@model yournamespace.Models.Book_View ?

Comment: @model Asset_Automation.ViewModel.BookIn_View

Comment: In your controller, you're assigning a value to the book property of Book_View class instead of book.asset. That might be the case. So when you try to access @item.asset, it will be throwing that exception

Comment: book is of type list

Comment: `@foreach (var item in Model.book)
{
      @item
}`                                                                                                                               Instead of @item.asset, just use @item and see if it throws the same exception. And I'm assuming till now you're getting the exception in your .cshtml file when trying to execute foreach loop, am I correct?

Comment: Then make sure your code `book = db.bookm.Where(x => x.date == date && x.In_time >= In_time&& x.out_time <= Out_time).ToList()` is returning some data. Put a debugger after at this block of code, and after this line executes, see what this book object contains. After that check your object bv, and see whether bv.book contains the value that you need